# getting error installing miRDeep2

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, perl

I am trying to install miRDeep2 on Ubuntu 14.04 using `perl install.pl` command as is suggested in "read me" file of the software. But I get the warning message below:

```
Warning: prerequisite Font::TTF 0 not found.
pdf was/is not installed properly
ttf was/is not installed properly
```

I also followed the manual installation commands as well but I still 
 get the same error. How can I install miRDeep2 successfully? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

open a bash, then type:

```
cpan
install Font::TTF
```

That should fix it.